# Erro [Forbidden] ao enviar evento no calendário do google, API googleCL

Tags: python, linux

Para quem não conhece, o **googleCl**(Command line tools for the Google Data APIs) segue o link https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/

Eu utilizo apenas o comando que que envia um evento para a minha agenda do google.

Agora tenho uma mensagem de erro, onde anteriormente rodava normal,
 simplesmente parou de funcionar de um tempo para cá, segue um exemplo do erro:

```
#google calendar add "teste"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/google", line 991, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/local/bin/google", line 977, in main
run_once(options, args)
File "/usr/local/bin/google", line 763, in run_once
task.run(client, options, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googlecl/calendar/__init__.py", line 330, in _run_add
results = client.quick_add_event(events_list, cal.user)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googlecl/calendar/service.py", line 277, in quick_add_event
USER_BATCH_URL_FORMAT % calendar_user)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/calendar/service.py", line 446, in ExecuteBatch
return self.Post(batch_feed, url, converter=converter)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googlecl/service.py", line 69, in retry_post
return self.retry_operation(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googlecl/base.py", line 394, in retry_operation
raise err
gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 403, 'body': '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Forbidden</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Forbidden</H1>\n<H2>Error 403</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n', 'reason': 'Forbidden'}
```

> Já atualizei a API para a ultima versão  (googlecl_0.9.14-2_all.deb) e nada, continua com mesmo erro

Comment: A requisição está retornando [403 Forbidden](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), deve ser esse o causador. Você está tentando acessar um recurso que o servidor não permite.

Comment: @qmechanik eu já vinha utilizando essa API há tempos, só se o google parou de aceitar inserção no calendário com essa API, porque indo lá via site o recurso continua disponível.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que o [**GoogleCL**](https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) utiliza a versão 2 do [**Calendar GData API**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/), que foi [descontinuado em novembro de 2014](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com.br/2014/06/calendar-gdata-api-google-calendar.html):

> Qualquer serviço dependente da Calendar GData API (v1, v2), como
>   o Google Calendar Connectors (*GCC*), deixará de funcionar como pretendido.
>   Usuários do *GCC* devem atualizar para usar o [*Calendário Interop*](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1330365) ou construir seus próprios conectores personalizados de modo que se sincronize com v3 da API.

Como o [**GoogleCL**](https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) não foi mais atualizado, a última vez foi em *dezembro de 2012*, não há suporte para *v3* do Calendar GData.

Como alternativa, pode-se usar o [**gcalcli**](https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli), que utiliza a [v3 do Calendar GData](https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli#google-calendar-command-line-interface). O lado negativo é que [**gcalcli**](https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli) não dá suporte para os outros serviços do Google, somente para o Calendário.

### Instalação

Para instalá-lo abra um terminal e digite o comando:

```
$ sudo pip install gcalcli
```

Se você não tiver o [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) instalado, faça o seguinte:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

### Utilização

Sintaxe:

```
gcalcli [opcoes] comando [argumentos ou opções de comando]
```

Para obter informações sobre o modo de uso, digite:

```
gcalcli --help
```

<sub>**Nota**: Na primeira vez que você utilizá-lo, será aberta uma página no navegador para pedir a autorização, é usado [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) para fazer a autenticação na conta.</sub>

Comment: rodou certinho aqui quando executo o comando direto no shell, só um detalhe, eu montei um script.sh e quando meu programa chama o script, no log ele pede p/ cadastrar novamente uma conta google, o script roda com usuário zabbix, que este já cadastrou uma conta google, dai fiquei boiando o porque no programa trava e da msg no log, e rodando direto do shell com usuário zabbix da certo, sabe me dizer o porque ou como resolver isso?