# google API - gcalcli - erro ao executar em um script

Tags: linux, shell-script, zabbix

Dando continuidade ao meu problema [relatado aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58449/erro-forbidden-ao-enviar-evento-no-calend%C3%A1rio-do-google-api-googlecl) agora eu consigo enviar eventos do *shell-script* diretamente para o google calendário, fiz um script para executar conforme programado, segue arquivo **sms.sh** abaixo

```
#!/bin/bash
let oneminf=`date +%s`+600
dateonemin=`date -d @$oneminf +%R`
gcalcli --calendar 'zabbix' --title "$3" --when $dateonemin --reminder '1m sms' --where '' --descr '' --duration 1 add > /dev/null 2>&1 >> /tmp/zabbix_server.log
```

> Este script foi foi elaborado com base nesse [link](http://arduinoprojexp.blogspot.com.br/2015/02/agentuino-zabbix-parte-4-google-agenda.html)

Quando executo ele diretamento do shell ele faz a inserção na agenda

```
$/etc/zabbix/scripts/sms.sh "[parametroZabbix]:PROBLEM"
```

Porém quando o programa zabbix dispara a trigger que chama esse arquivo **sms.sh** ele me da uma mensagem de saída assim:

```
    Sign in with your Google Account

[avatar_2x]

Email [                    ] Password [                    ] [Sign in] Need
help?
Create an account

One Google Account for everything Google

[logo_strip_2x]

  â¢ Google
  â¢ Privacy
  â¢ Terms
```

Já fiz o comando *$gcalcli agenda --noauth_local_webserver* com o usuário *zabbix* que é o usuário que executa a aplicação, e mesmo assim ele continua dando esse erro.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54269/discussion-on-question-by-sneeps-ninja-google-api-gcalcli-erro-ao-executar-e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para quem estiver ainda interessado eu reiniciei a maquina ( linux ) e voltou a funcionar normalmente, muito estranho...